# Is it valid to use ArgumentOutOfRangeException where the "range" is not numeric in nature?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

For example, suppose I write a method that accepts a string as input, and I stipulate that the string should contain only ASCII characters. If the caller passes in a string containing a non-ASCII character, is it valid to throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException, or should ArgumentException be used?

[The page for ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) says that it is "the exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method". It doesn't say in so many words that the "range" in question is numeric, so for a sufficiently abstract definition of "range" (a subset of the universe of possible values for the type) one could argue that the ASCII string example fits. We might well refer to "the range of strings that are ASCII". However, all of the examples on that page are in fact numeric. Indeed, they are all integers; and all but one involve integer indexes into a sequence or collection of some kind (the only one that doesn't fit this pattern is the one about the ages of party guests, at the bottom of the page).

Comment: no in this case we do not throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: just throw argumentexception

Comment: It does not matter much which one you will throw in this case really. Just choose whatever you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says:

> [Range (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range), a set containing the output values produced by a function.

and also

> [Set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory): [...] sets [...] are collections of objects. [...] any type of object can be collected into a set [...].

Functions can return objects of any type, even in mathematics. They need not to be numbers. They can be matrices, functions (in C# these would be delegates), truth values, sets, persons, colors, and so on.

So yes, you can use a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for other types than numbers. But since the term "range" is very often accociated with contiguous number ranges, it is probably more intuitive to use `ArgumentException`.